# Аналог site-auditor ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

С недавнего времени adobe-air перестал работать под linux а wine версия не устанавливает site-auditor. Подскажите кто знает подобную программу которая просматривала бы позиции сайта, хотябы под wine чтобы запускалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему проще запустил под вайном виндовс версию напрямую, безовсяких аиров :)